# firebase push notification header content-type error found "content type : is missing error"

Tags: laravel, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

Firebase push notification all code working fine just issue header not found Content-Type is missing but I'm sending in curl

Answer (score 0):

just Remove ":" colon in your header

**'Content-Type:' =>'application/json'**
after remove colon

**'Content-Type' =>'application/json'**

also, try to update your [Push Notification Package v5.0.0](https://github.com/Edujugon/PushNotification)